# Python: Splitting numbers and factor them to 2

Tags: python

This code is to identify if the number factored to 2 for the 4th time, would get 1 or not.

```
a = int(input())
terms = 4
result = list(map(lambda x: a ** x, range(terms)))
for i in range(terms):
   print(a, "^2 = ", result[i])
if result == 1:
   print('True')
else:
   print('False')
```

If I input 14, this is the result:

```
14 ^2 =  1
14 ^2 =  14
14 ^2 =  196
14 ^2 =  2744
False
```

But I want it to be like this.

```
1^2 + 4^2 = 17
1^2 + 7^2 = 50
5^2 + 0^2 = 25
2^2 + 5^2 = 29
False
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure you got "nothing", or were there errors that were raised?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want, but at least I can say that you compare list and number, which makes no sense

Comment: I got one error which is:
:for b, c in str(a):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: I cannot figure out what you think "for b, c in str(a)" should do. str(a) will just return a, because a is already a string.

Comment: I will edit and put my original code which is working, but it's not the result that I want.

Comment: Python is indees a dynamic language, so the same variable can contain an int or a string **at different times**. But `int` and `str` are different types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = str(int(input()))

def split_and_print(a):
    x = [int(y) for y in list(str(a))]
    return sum([y**2 for y in x])

def split_sum_print(a):
    a_split = list(str(a))
    print(' + '.join([x+'^2' for x in a])+ ' = '+str(split_and_print(a)))
    return str(split_and_print(a))

n = 4 
for i in range(n):
    a = split_sum_print(a)
if a == '1':
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Output:

```
14
1^2 + 4^2 = 17
1^2 + 7^2 = 50
5^2 + 0^2 = 25
2^2 + 5^2 = 29
False
```

I made two functions, one responsible for calculation, the other for printing. Then combined them and used a `for` loop. Change `n` for different number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `a = str(int(input()))` seems quite unnecessary, as `input()` returns string by itself.

Second, you then cast it to string `... in str(a):` once again *(again unnecessary)*.

And third of all, you are iterating over some string (`a` in this case), which would product a stream of single characters, but your code is written as if you expected [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) instead...?

**For example**

```
for char in "abc":
  print(char)
```

... would print

```
a
b
c
```

**What you essentially have**

```
for a, b in "abc":
  print(a, b)
```

... what should happen here?

What do you expect to happen with your code, exactly?